# C++ does not recognize string as keyword

Tags: c++, string, exception, keyword

I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
     char string[4]='xyz';  
     return 0;
}
```

Since string is a keyword the compiler should give error but it runs fine. Can anyone explain why it compiles successfully.

Comment: `string` is not a keyword.

Comment: `string` isn't a keyword, it's just an identifier in the `std` namespace. You have created a new identifier `string` that's local to your main function.

Comment: Also I assume you meant `"xyz"` not `'xyz'`.

Comment: Also, while `<iostream>` *might* include `<string>`, it's not guaranteed or specified anywhere. If you want to use `std::string` you should always explicitly include the `<string>` header.

Comment: You may want to look up "variable shadowing".

Comment: @AndreasWenzel -- good suggestion, but note that shadowing applies to all names, not just the names of variables. In this case, the name of the variable `string` shadows the global (because of, you know, `using namespace std`) name of the type `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is not a keyword.

It's the name of a type declared in the standard library.

When you give it a name, you're doing something called shadowing. This is more clear in the following example:

```
{
    int x = 0;
    
    {
        int x = 5;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

What gets printed?

Well, `5` first then `0`.

This is because the x in the second scope overrides the x from the first. It "shadows" the first declaration.

This works with typenames as well:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
};

...

{
    ...
    int MyStruct = 10;
    ...
}
```

Here, MyStruct gets overridden within that scope.

That same thing happens in your example with `std::string`